# jQuery - Grand total with multiple totals

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the `sum of totals` for each item (`item` and `item2`). I nested the sum function inside of an each function with the item as the selector.

How do I get the `sum` of every unique item's `total` to calculate the grand total for all `item` and `item2`?

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  const item = $(this);
  var qty = $(this).find(".qty").text();
  var price = $(this).find(".cost").text();
  var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
  $(this).find(".total").text(total);
  var sum = 0;
  $(".total").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(
      $(this).text());
  });
  $("#grand").text(sum);
});
$(".item2").each(function() {
  const item = $(this);
  var qty = $(this).find(".qty").text();
  var price = $(this).find(".cost").text();
  var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
  $(this).find(".total").text(total);
  var sum = 0;
  $(".total").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(
      $(this).text());
  });
  $("#grand2").text(sum);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex
}

.item,
.item2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
}

.item2 {
  border-color: blue
}

.total {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="cost">25</div>
  <div class="qty">45</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="cost">65</div>
  <div class="qty">105</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="cost">15</div>
  <div class="qty">95</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div id="grand">0</div>
<div class="item2">
  <div class="cost">65</div>
  <div class="qty">105</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <div class="cost">15</div>
  <div class="qty">95</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div id="grand2">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code some. Let me know if it makes sense.

```js
var grand = 0, total;

$(".item").each(function(){
  grand += (total = ($(this).find(".qty").text() * $(this).find(".cost").text()));
  $(this).find(".total").text(total);
});
$("#grand").text(grand);

grand = 0;
$(".item2").each(function(){
  grand += (total = ($(this).find(".qty").text() * $(this).find(".cost").text()));
  $(this).find(".total").text(total);
});
$("#grand2").text(grand);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex
}

.item,
.item2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50px;
}

.item2 {
  border-color: blue
}

.total {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="cost">25</div>
  <div class="qty">45</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="cost">65</div>
  <div class="qty">105</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="cost">15</div>
  <div class="qty">95</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div id="grand">0</div>
<div class="item2">
  <div class="cost">65</div>
  <div class="qty">105</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <div class="cost">15</div>
  <div class="qty">95</div>
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
<div id="grand2">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed as little as possible, but this could be refactored if you felt up for it

You're JS needs to be more like the following:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = $(this).find(".qty").text();
    var price = $(this).find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    $(this).find(".total").text(total);
});

var sum1 = 0;
$(".item .total").each(function() {
    sum1 += parseInt(
    $(this).text());
});
$("#grand").text(sum1);

$(".item2").each(function() {
    const item = $(this);
    var qty = $(this).find(".qty").text();
    var price = $(this).find(".cost").text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    $(this).find(".total").text(total);
});

var sum2 = 0;
$(".item2 .total").each(function() {
    sum2 += parseInt(
    $(this).text());
});
$("#grand2").text(sum2);
```

You are resetting `sum` to `0` for each `.item` that you loop through, effectively keeping the total at `0`. On top of that, you are trying to loop through all `.total`s for each `.item`. I.e. if you have 3 items, you would call to `.totals` 9 times. I've pulled out the variable declaration (`sum1` and `sum2`) as well as pulled the actual totaling loops out of the items loop to get past this.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6xqg74by/